# What am I buying?

Tags: anagram

I'm shopping for an item with the following shopping list:

1. Try taco, (a creek in Oregon)
2. [Make it more +3X hsv], those cycles.
3. Energetic ball auto-caller
4. EWNICW XLJW & XEIXJWE DEIN TIYE EWAYKR

What one item am I looking for?